# htaccess mod_rewrite expression for specific url structure

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, structure

I have a URL-structure like this:

```
mypage.com/search/f7_987_Aprilia/f8_1234_Aprilia+RS+125
mypage.com/search/f7_987_Aprilia
mypage.com/search/f8_1234_Aprilia+RS+125
```

And I need them to route internally (without redirection) to the following structure:

```
mypage.com/search?&f[7]=987&f[8]=1234
mypage.com/search?&f[7]=987
mypage.com/search?&f[8]=1234
```

I have come this far: /(f\d+)*(\d+)*.*/
This gives me the desired IDs in the first set. But how do I get the parameters separated by slashes? And how do I "convert" to the desired structure?

Is that possible with htaccess?

I hope there is a genius out there who can come up with the desired mod_rewrite regex

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this code in site root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^search/([a-z])(\d)_(\d+)_[^/]*/?$ search?&$1[$2]=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^search/([a-z])(\d)_(\d+)_[^/]*/([a-z])(\d)_(\d+)_[^/]*/([a-z])(\d)_(\d+)_[^/]*/?$ search?&$1[$2]=$3&$4[$5]=$6 [L,QSA,NC]
```